# enabling store_events doesn't capture floatingip metering

Tags: openstack, ceilometer

I set 'store_events' to true under [notifications] in ceilometer.conf file for capturing floating ip metering.

But on creating a floating ip, it is not captured by ceilometer.
When I am checking ceilometer meter-list, no meters are available for floating ips.

Is there any other config parameter that need to be enabled for this?